# Angular 4 context lost after authentication

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, adal, adal.js

I am using ng2-adal for authentication. Angular 4 route lost after authentication. On running project, homepage URL is : 'http://localhost:31334/index.html/home'. On successful authentication, I navigate to route as : `this.router.navigate(["/upload"])`. However, on successful authentication, browser shows url as : http://localhost:31334/upload. As a result, page CSS is lost and page doesn't display properly. **app.route.ts** file looks as:

```
export const router: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'upload', component: UploadComponent },
    { path: 'explore', component: ExploreComponent }
];

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);
```

Authentication service is as:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SecretService 
{
    public get adalConfig(): any {
        return {
            tenant: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com',
            clientId: 'xxxxyyyyzzzzaaaabbbb',
            redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
            postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/'
        };
    }
}
```

Changing to below, keeps on URL : http://localhost:31334/index.html/ after successful authentication and doesn't navigate to 'Upload'. After that, clicking 'Upload' link displays 'Upload' page with all CSS and formatting intact.

```
export class SecretService 
    {
        public get adalConfig(): any {
            return {
                tenant: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com',
                clientId: 'xxxxyyyyzzzzaaaabbbb',
                redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/index.html',
                postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/index.html'
            };
        }
    }
```

Separately navigation to route `this.router.navigate(["/upload"])` on a button click without authentication displays the upload page successfully.

To resolve this, I added `<base href="/index.html/">` in index.html and used `window.location.origin + "/index.html"` in authentication component. Also in the root component constructor, I redirected to home component as : `this.router.navigate(['home']);`

This reloads the angular context and I am not able to maintain the state like the user is always reported as unauthenticated even after successful authentication as angular context is being reloaded I believe.

Please suggest how to achieve the correct behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `<base href="/index.html/">` in the `<head>` of your **index.html**.

Comment: I added `<base href="/index.html/">` to hide index.html from appearing in URL. However, after successful authentication, I stay on root url ` http://localhost:31334/` and not redirected to correct path. In getAdal() method, I changed to : `redirectUri: this.router.navigate['upload'],
            postLogoutRedirectUri: this.router.navigate['home']` still on root url after successful authentication. Also `redirectUri: ''` makes no difference & I am redirected to root instead of 'upload' route

Comment: Adding `<base href>` doesn't hide `/index.html` from appearing, it tells the router to consider the base URL as `yourdomain.com/index.html`.